# Get folder's attributes with Javascript in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, directory, photoshop-script

I want to get a folder's attributes, especially whether it is hidden. The script for Photoshop CC is written in JavaScript, and I am running Windows 10.

Unfortunately, the manual does not mention any method like `attributes`, therefore this code **does not work**:

```
var f = Folder('/c/Windows');
if (f.attributes & 2) {
    alert('Folder is hidden');
}
```

Does anybody know a way to at least find out whether a given folder is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's [JavaScript Tools Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf#page=59) has the details for the File and Folder objects. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is any attribute to expose the hidden status.

You can have your script perform command line tasks, so if you know of a way through the OS command line to see this detail you could try having your script execute that command and getting the result.

Comment: Patrick, that would be a way. I am running Windows 10, and with the command `attrib`, I could show a folder's attributes. But how can I execute a command AND evaluate its output?

Comment: Execute a command that creates a output file of a predetermined name, so you script would assume that files existence after running the command and read in the file to see the output. It is not very elegant but I have done that successfully.

Comment: Patrick, how exactly would I execute a command via Javascript? Can you give a code example how I would execute `dir c:\ > C:\output.txt`?

Comment: You would have to create a .bat file with your command in it (assuming you are on Windows; you can use a .sh file if you are on Mac), then reference that file and use the execute() method. Example: 

`new File("c:/Users/Patrick/test.bat").execute();`